# Google Oauth2, can't retrieve one-time authorization code

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an android app that obtains access to google services by requesting an onetime authorization code. Each time the user logs in the auth code is retrieved from Google.
It worked well for a while but stopped working for a specific user.
This user keep getting `UserRecoverableAuthException` So Googles permissions request screen keep showing again and again.
When I try to obtain normal access token to this user, there is no problem.

The code I use:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
             try 
             {
                // Obtaining normal access token for testing propose.
                String tempToken  = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), mAccountName, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
                NLog.i(TAG, "Got token2: "+tempToken);          
                // Obtaining One time auth code
                String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s",CLIENT_ID, TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
                mServerToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), mAccountName, scope);
                NLog.i(TAG, "Got code: "+mServerToken);
                sendGoogleLoginResult(RESULT_OK, null, mServerToken);
                finish();
            } 
             catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) 
             {
                if (e !=null && e.getIntent() != null && authExceptionCount <3)
                {
                    authExceptionCount++;
                    Intent recoveryIntent = e.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(recoveryIntent, GOOGLE_RECOVERY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "UserRecoverableAuthException but there was no intent: ", e);
                    sendGoogleLoginResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null, mServerToken);
                    finish();
                }
            } 
             catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "transient error encountered: ", e);
                sendGoogleLoginResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null, mServerToken);
                finish();

            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                // This is likely unrecoverable.
                 Log.e(TAG, "Unrecoverable authentication exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                 sendGoogleLoginResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null, mServerToken);
                 finish();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: But you have two calls to getToken() in the same try/catch, so how do you know which one sent you the UserRecoverableAuthException... Oh I guess you can look in logcat. So you’re saying this works for certain users but not others?  Is the user it doesn’t work for on an odd/different device?  Any further information you could provide would be useful.

Comment: Right, I can tell by looking at the logcat. The two calls are for testing reasons (Added the first one to check if it happens on normal token request, and apparently it doesn't). The problem seems to be device depended, as all users fail to connect on this device and successfully connect on other devices.

Comment: If the issue is on a particular device, then you may not have the right code/update on that device and that is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Hm, you might go into settings/apps on a failing device and check the version of Google Play Services. It’s not impossible you could fix it by refreshing from Play store.